# Select rows with string type that has a substring of digits >= N (For example: N = 9)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with column ABC that is containing a string with the pattern shown below,

> 8~1~0~1~0~0~2~0~5~6

The individual digits usually vary between 0 to 100.

Can you help me with the query to filter all the rows that has at least 3 digits that are >= 5. That query should eventually filter the above record as it has 5,6 & 8

Comment: Structured Query Language is significantly easier when data is structured. Like one value per column in each row. Use joins where necessary.

Comment: This is not possible with the current table structure. see DB normalization. first normal form each field contains a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) operator which can solve this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ABC RLIKE '(([1-9][0-9]+|[5-9])(~|$).*){3}' ... ;
```